# Const and Non-Const Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I have a topic I'm confused on that I need some elaborating on. It's operator overloading with a const version and a non-const version.

```
// non-const
double &operator[](int idx) {
    if (idx < length && idx >= 0) {
        return data[idx];
    }
    throw BoundsError();
}
```

I understand that this lambda function, takes an index and checks its validity and then returns the index of the array data in the class. There's also a function with the same body but with the function call as

```
const double &operator[](int idx) const
```

Why do we need two versions?

For example, on the sample code below, which version is used in each instance below?

```
Array a(3);
a[0] = 2.0;
a[1] = 3.3;
a[2] = a[0] + a[1];
```

My hypothesis that the const version is only called on `a[2]` because we don't want to risk modifying `a[0]` or `a[1]`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can easily check which is called with output inside them.

Comment: it's in a lecture slide so I was hoping I wouldn't have to create a class to utilize them, instead just someone help me understand why we do this

Comment: Don't be lazy, try it out for yourself, you'll remember better.

Comment: _My hypothesis that the const version is only called on `a[2]` because we don't want to risk modifying `a[0]` or `a[1]`._ This makes no sense, the operation `a[2]` doesn't involve `a[0]` or `a[1]`, it involves `a` and the integer literal `2`.

Comment: I found this video helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fJBrditnJU . Jump directly to 8:15

Answer (score 44):

When both versions are available, the logic is pretty straightforward: `const` version is called for `const` objects, non-`const` version is called for non-`const` objects. That's all.

In your code sample `a` is a non-`const` object, meaning that the non-`const` version is called in all cases. The `const` version is *never* called in your sample.

The point of having two versions is to implement "read/write" access for non-`const` objects and only "read" access for `const` objects. For `const` objects `const` version of `operator []` is called, which returns a `const double &` reference. You can read data through that const reference, but your can't write through it.

Comment: I don't know -- I found it difficult to get the non-const version called.  See this live demo please : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c820d80113bc9e3

Comment: @Reb.Cabin: In your demo, you never make any attempts to call the non-const version of `operator[]`. Every time you have such opportunity, you use `this->elems[i]` instead. Note that `this->elems` is an ordinary raw pointer. Its operator `[]` is the ordinary *built-in* indexer, not your overloaded indexer. If you want to call your overloaded non-const version of `operator []`, you have to use `(*this)[i]` on the left-hand side of assignments, not `this->elems[i]`.

Comment: I see. I re-wrote the ctor and a better example to use the non-const indexer. Helpful, clarifying comment. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a2e3960c1e77d78

Comment: @AnT In case of a relation operator overloading, should we provide both or just one is enough? In that case, which one should we use. E.g. `bool operator<(const Type &t) const` or `bool operator<(const Type &t)` is better?

Answer (score 6):

To supply a code example to complement the answer above:

```
Array a(3);
a[0] = 2.0;  //non-const version called on non-const 'a' object

const Array b(3);
double var = b[1];  //const version called on const 'b' object

const Array c(3);
c[0] = 2.0;  //compile error, cannot modify const object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if there was an option like

```
double k = 3.0;
```

and the array's elements were const

```
a[0] = a[1] + k; or std::cout << a[0] + k;
```

the `const double &operator[](int idx) const` version would have been called. Here you are adding non-const variable to const object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).