# what does "const" mean when overloading operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I saw something like:

```
const char& operator[] (int Index) const
```

the first `const` I understand. It's to protect the returning `char` from being modified.

But what does second `const` mean? Why do we sometimes use two `const`, sometimes just one?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237411/const-and-non-const-operator-overloading?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be used for any member function, not only operators. It means, that this function will:

- not be able to modify any data members (except `mutable` ones)
- will not be able to call any non-`const` member functions

Comment: I always like to say it's the way to specify the constness of the implicit `this` pointed to object.

Comment: do the mutable ones mean local variables in side the function?

Comment: @user3429675 - no, they are regular data members, that can be changed in `const` functions. `mutable` is a keyword, like `const` for example. A mutable data member could be: `mutable int x;` for example.