# Difference between const char[] and char[]

Tags: c++, arrays, string, constants

```
Marray(char MyString [])
Marray(const char MyString [])
```

What is the difference between these two lines? I was reading about difference between `const char*` and `char*`. Is it the same with `char[]` and `const char []`?
I am confused, since in both cases, when I overload operator [], change of the string literal is possible. **`const char*` is a mutable pointer to an immutable character/string.** -- So I was expecting the same with `const char []`, but the string is mutable...

more code:

constructor:

```
Marray::Marray(const char MyString []){
    length = 0;

    while(MyString[length]!=NULL){  
        length ++;
    }

    text= new char [length+1];

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
        *(text+i)=MyString[i];
    text[length]=NULL;
}

char & Marray::operator[] (int i) const { return text[i];}

int main () {

    Marray n("String");

    n[3]='d';

    n.getMarray();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I got after running:

> Strdng

So, the string is changed, even though there is `const char[]`.

Comment: What do you mean by overloading operator [] here? You are using built-in types, and you cannot overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: I am not using built-in types. I am not sure whether Array is reserved word in C++, I have just translated it from my mother tongue(sorry for that). When I create an object of the class array, and when I try to change string array (I am using overloaded operator [] for that), it is possible, even though this - Array(const char MyString []) - is my constructor.

Comment: @MMM You might want to edit your question so it shows the code of your constructors. Do they use C-style casting or `const_cast`? I guess they do, but cannot be sure when the code isn't there.

Comment: Oh, so your `Array` is a class, and you're showing the constructors for that class. That was not clear to me. Anyway, it doesn't matter what your `operator[]` looks like, the compiler will detect any attempts to modify read-only strings unless you cast the `const` away (and you generally should not do that). Could you show some more code that explains how you're modifying a string literal? It will either show that what you're modifying really isn't a string literal, or you're casting away `const` somewhere, but there's no telling which without more information.

Comment: I will show some more code. Thank you.

Comment: When it is given a readonly string, your class makes a writable copy.  It's unclear why you think being able to write to a copy is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

> I was reading about difference between `const char*` and `char*`. Is it the same with `char[]` and `const char []`?

For most practical purposes, the answer is "yes". Although generally `char const*` and `char const[]` are two different types, one can become the other based on the context. In this specific context (a declaration of a function parameter) they do mean the same thing.

> So I was expecting the same with `const char []`, but the string is mutable

No, the C string passed into the function remains constant due to the `const` qualifier ([demo](http://ideone.com/LyEMBk)). An attempt to modify `const char MyString[]` inside `Array` would produce a compile-time error:

> error: assignment of read-only location ‘* s’

Comment: No, `char const*` and `char const[]` are two different types from which one is contextually decayed to the other. Rephrase your first sentence.

Comment: @Columbo Here, they mean exactly the same thing, because they're function parameters. Inside the function body, `decltype(MyString)` will be `char *` or `const char *`, not `char []` nor `const char []`.

Comment: @Columbo: in a function declaration they are identical!

Comment: @hvd Yes, *here*. Of course. His sentence sounded quite general though, didn't it?

Comment: @Columbo In this context, `char const[]` is *adjusted* to `char const*`. There is no decaying, and the types are exactly the same.

Comment: @juanchopanza You can also call this type adjustment. I refer to it as a decay at times, which is probably incorrect (I will call it adjustment from now on). Perhaps that term should only be used for the decaying of array lvalues/rvalues to a corresponding pointer.

Comment: @Columbo If it was so clear what you meant, everybody wouldn't be jumping onto this. :) It looked to me as if you might have missed the part of the question that says they're function parameters, and even if you didn't miss that, it was still worth clarifying, I think.

Comment: @juanchopanza No. `char const[]` isn't the same as `char const*`. If you meant to say that `char const*` is the same as what `char const[]` is adjusted to, i.e. `char const*`, that was a tautology.

Comment: @Columbo The type of a function parameter is *adjusted*. An array *decays* to a pointer as an implicit conversion. Some people like to be extra pedantic about something that is already pedantic.

Comment: *+1* Now that the sentence has been clarified.

Comment: @Columbo: the key difference is: you can't overload on the declaration of function parameters only differing in the use of `T[]` (or `T[n]` for that matter) and `T*`. You can interchange the notation (for function parameters) arbitrarily.

Comment: "Decaying" isn't the right term here. In this case, the parameter type is treated as thought it were a pointer, not an array. The standard describes it as a transformation. Decaying (synonymous with array-to-pointer conversion) is what allows an array to be easily passed in the form of a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @Joseph To be fair, "decaying" isn't standard terminology anyway.

Comment: Now the explanation is wrong! There is **no** decay involved for function parameters!

Comment: @remyabel True, but it does have a well accepted meaning.

Comment: @Joseph I disagree. It's obvious from this conversation here that it's confusing. I pointed this out to another user weeks ago and got a response about "teaching a man to fish"...

Comment: @remyabel The standard library does provide a `std::decay` template. :o)

Answer (score 2):

First off, according to 8.5.3 [dcl.fct] paragaph 5 the function argument types are adjusted to be pointer types:

> ... After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively.

That is, the question becomes "What's the difference between passing `T*` and `T const*`?" and the obvious answer is, the `const`ness of the objects pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor with the `const` only promises not to change the parameter it receives. That is, it promises that the following code will write `String`:

```
char mystring[] = "String";
Marray n(mystring);
std::cout << mystring;
```

However, your class *wants* to provide the service of changing its contents *even when passed an immutable string* - so it *must* copy the string into another storage, which is mutable.

If you want to have the effect you described, you can make an immutable object:

```
char mystring[] = "String";
const Marray n(mystring);
n[3]='d'; // compilation error
```

---

Update: As noted by hvd in a comment, to make the compiler issue an error, you will need to fix the declaration of `operator[]`:

```
char& Marray::operator[] (int i) { return text[i];} // non-const version
const char& Marray::operator[] (int i) const { return text[i];} // const version
```

or (better)

```
char& Marray::operator[] (int i) { return text[i];} // non-const version
char Marray::operator[] (int i) const { return text[i];} // const version
```

(see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19237455/509868) to find out why you need 2 versions of the same operator).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, basically, if the constructor is without const, it might happen that the parameter it receives changes? Is it than a good habit to always go with the const?

Comment: This answer is not quite right. The `operator[]` in the question is declared `const`, yet returns `char &`. `n[3]='d';` will not cause any compilation error. The class is effectively designed so that `const` has lost its meaning for that specific class.

Comment: @MMM No, the parameter it receives doesn't change. It doesn't change at all. As hinted at in this answer, you're copying the data into new storage, and that new storage is what you then modify, not the original string literal.

Comment: I am returning char & which means that I am modifying original string, not its copy. Am I right? And it is working the same regardless of the const(it only means that return value is not modifiable?) I am new to C++, this is probably trivial, I'm sorry.@hvd

Comment: @MMM Your constructor makes a copy and forgets the original, so there's no way the `operator[]` could change the original, whether `const` or not `const`. To change the original, you'd have to add deliberate support.

Comment: Right, @MMM, anatolyg's previous comment is correct, but let me elaborate a little: you're returning `text[i]`, so the caller gets to modify the string pointed to by `text`. In your constructor, you've written `text= new char [length+1];`. Therefore, `text` always points to modifiable memory, it's not the same pointer as the constructor argument `MyString`.

Comment: @anatolyg But it is not copy constructor. Thus I assumed that I am working with the original.