# C++ error: operator[] cannot be overloaded

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am learning C++ and studying Chapter 18 of Vandevoorde and Josuttis's C++ Templates. I retyped their code for Expression Templates, but the following is producing the error

```
sarray1.cpp:36:6: error: ‘T& SArray<T>::operator[](size_t) const’ cannot be overloaded
   T& operator[] (size_t idx) const {
      ^
sarray1.cpp:32:5: error: with ‘T SArray<T>::operator[](size_t) const’
   T operator[] (size_t idx) const {
```

Here's the code:

```
template <typename T>
class SArray {

public:

...

  T operator[] (size_t idx) const {
    return storage[idx];
  }

  T& operator[] (size_t idx) const {
    return storage[idx];
  }
...
};
```

I am just learning C++ so I hadn't seen an instance of an overloaded function that differed only be return type, but I see that this is indeed done: [Overload a C++ function according to the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value). I also see that `[]` is not on the [list of operators that cannot be  overloaded](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-14/) in C++. I can't think of what else could be going wrong. What is the reason for the above error?

Comment: Not sure, but seems to be related: [Const and Non-Const Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237411/const-and-non-const-operator-overloading) if the `const` on the `T&` version is a mistake?

Comment: Yes, the const on the second line is a mistake, as was shown in one of the answers below. However, I'll leave the question un edited so the reply makes sense. Sorry about this type, all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake when re-typing the code from page 323. Only the first overload should be `const`, while the second one should be non-`const`:

```
T operator[] (size_t idx) const {
    return storage[idx];
}

T& operator[] (size_t idx) { // <<== No const here
    return storage[idx];
}
```

The point this code is trying to illustrate is that you can overload an operator on `const`-ness of `this` object. C++ will figure out from the context which of the two operators it should call, and then either return a reference when `SArray` is non-const, or return a copy when the array is `const`.

Comment: Ugh, you're right. What a terrible question. My apologies.

Comment: @sunny No worries here: overloading on `const` is a particularly tough thing to spot if you have never seen this trick before. Good news is that it makes you watch out for `const`-ness of operators in the future, helping you avoid potential confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you can't overload on the return type. If you read the question and answer that you linked ([Overload a C++ function according to the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value)), you would see that a workaround is required.

However, you really have to ask what you are doing this? Is there a simpler solution?

You probably should have one `const` method, and one non-`const` method:

```
const T& operator[] (size_t idx) const {
  return storage[idx];
}

T& operator[] (size_t idx)  {
  return storage[idx];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload by return type in C++. What's considered are the arguments and, for member functions, the qualification. In this case, I'm guessing what you meant to do was:

```
// a non-const member function to return a non-const reference
T& operator[] (size_t idx) {
    return storage[idx];
}

// a const member function to return a const reference
const T& operator[] (size_t idx) const {
    return storage[idx];
}
```

This way, the `const` member function will be called if `this` is a pointer to `const` (because the non-`const` function is not viable) and the non-`const` function will be called otherwise (because it will be a better match).