# Multiple operator[] overloads

Tags: c++

Take a look at this simple array class

```
class Array {
    const unsigned int _size;
    int _array[100];

public:
    Array() : _size(100) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
            _array[i] = 0;
    }

    int& operator[](unsigned int index) {
        cout << "normal operator[].\n";
        return _array[index];
    }

    const int& operator[](unsigned int index) const {
        cout << "const operator[].\n";
        return _array[index];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array a;

    a[3] = 1;
    cout << a[3] << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The "normal operator[]" line is executed twice, though I would expect the second call (`cout << a[3] << "\n";`) to be using the const version of the overloaded operator, because it doesn't change the array itself.

Why is that? Is there a way to force the const version to be called as I wish?

Comment: `a` isn't `const` in that expression, so the const overload isn't called. If you want to force it you can use `const_cast<Array const&>(a)[3]` but it really isn't necessary.

Comment: What's the point then? I'm trying to mimic std::vector as it also has two overloaded operator[] functions. Are you saying that unless the std::vector object is const (as I see no point in that), the non-const version will always be called?

Comment: `unless the std::vector object is const the non-const version will always be called` this is (sort of) the definition of a `const` overload, yes. Note that the underlying object itself might be non-const and is being accessed through a const reference, which is usually the case. In your code for instance you could also use `Array const& b = a; cout << b[3];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Const and Non-Const Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237411/const-and-non-const-operator-overloading)

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: `system(pause)`... you know you can tell your IDE to not auto-close console windows, right?

Comment: I prefer that line though. @casey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an overloaded const version of a method, the const version will be called when the object is const. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:

    void foo()
    {
        cout << "foo()" << endl;
    }

    void foo() const
    {
        cout << "foo() const" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass a;
    const MyClass b;

    a.foo();
    b.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

will call the normal `foo()` for the object `a`, and the const version for the object `b`.

In your case, you just have to avoid trying to assign to the const version. For example:

```
Array a;
const Array b;

a[3] = 1;
// b[3] = 1; // error
cout << a[3] << "\n";
cout << b[3] << "\n";
```

works fine. But if you try to make the assignment to `b`, you get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostream &operator<<(int x)` doesn't take its parameter as `const` (because const isn't useful when passing by value), so the non-const `operator[]` can be called.

So, when will `const operator[]` be called?

It is true that a `const vector` variable declaration is almost always useless aside from some edge cases. The primary reason `const operator[]` is important, and the most often you will see it used, is calling it on a reference parameter.

```
int readStuff(const std::vector<int> &dontMutateMe) {
    return dontMutateMe[42]; // const
}
```

[Constant reference parameters are valuable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967177/when-to-use-const-and-const-reference-in-function-args), and this code wouldn't work without `const operator[]`.

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<`'s parameter declaration has nothing to do with the overload selected for `a`,  the non-`const` `operator[]` would still be called if it were declared `int const& x`.