# Why won't overloaded operator> work when the arguments are declared const?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am writing a program that models a trick-taking card game. In the function that determines the winner of the trick, I create a `list` of all the cards whose suit matches the suit of the card led. I then sort that list in descending order by rank and then return the first card in the `list` (i.e. the card with the highest rank of those that match the suit led). This is the relevant portion of the code:

```
#include <list>

enum Suits
{
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Hearts,
    Spades
};

class Card
{
private:
    const Suits suit;
    const int rank;
    friend Card determineWinner(Card led, Card other1, Card other2, Card other3);
public:
    Card(Suits cardsSuit, int cardsRank) : suit(cardsSuit), rank(cardsRank) {}
    bool operator > (const Card& compareTo)
    {
        return (rank > compareTo.rank);
    }
};

Card determineWinner(Card led, Card other1, Card other2, Card other3)
{
    Suits ledSuit = led.suit;
    list<Card> eligible = { led };
    // add the cards whose suit matches the suit led to the list of cards eligible to win the trick
    if (other1.suit == ledSuit)
        eligible.push_back(other1);
    if (other2.suit == ledSuit)
        eligible.push_back(other2);
    if (other3.suit == ledSuit)
        eligible.push_back(other3);
    // sort the list of cards eligible to win the trick in descending order by rank
    eligible.sort([](const Card& card1, const Card& card2) {return (card1 > card2);});
    // the highest ranked eligible card is first in the list after the sort
    auto winner = eligible.begin();
    return *winner;
}
```

When I attempt to run this code, I get a compile error: `E0349: no operator ">" matches these operands`. If I declare `card1` and `card2` as non-`const` in the lambda function I use as my sort predicate, the code compiles and performs as expected. Is there something I can change in the definition of `Card`'s `operator >` that will allow this to compile with `card1` and `card2` declared `const`, or should I just leave well enough alone?

Comment: Your `operator>` needs to be declared as a `const` member function. On another note, I would declare it not as a member function, but as a free function (possibly a `friend`)

Comment: Your operator overload needs to be const as well. [This previous question might give more context.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237411/const-and-non-const-operator-overloading)

Comment: Side note:  You should overload the other relational operators such as `<` `==`, etc.  As a matter of fact, those are the only ones that you really need to fully implement, and derive the others from those two.  It makes little sense to be able to compare for `>` and not for `<`, `<=`, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have the other relational operators defined, but didn't include them in the excerpt I provided here so as to avoid clogging the question with extra code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> bool operator > (const Card& compareTo)
> {
>     return (rank > compareTo.rank);
> }
> ```

This needs to be declared as a const member function. Member functions that don't have the `const` qualifier attached to their signature cannot be called on `const` objects, as without this qualifier, the compiler doesn't know for certain that no changes are made to the object's state in that function—and if you include `const` in the signature, the compiler will enforce this contract, and fail to compile if you attempt to alter the state of the object inside this function.

Corrected code looks like this:

```
bool operator > (const Card& compareTo) const
{
    return (rank > compareTo.rank);
}
```

Comment: When I declare the operator as `const`, can I still use it to compare non-`const` instances of `class Card`?

Comment: Yes - please see item 3 in S. Meyers book Effective C++

Comment: @train1855 Yes. `T &` can be implicitly assigned to `T const&` with no `const`-casting or other similar mechanism, which means a function like `void do_something(std::string const& str)` will bind to an invocation like `std::string str = "Howdy!"; do_something(str);`, with no issues. So in your case, `bool operator>(Card const& card) const` will work regardless of whether the left-hand-side is `const` or not, or whether the right-hand-side is `const` or not.